# analog lowpass Butterworth filter - Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter

I'm trying to generate a lowpass analog butterworth filter on my data

The data files

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/m5wx8h4vj4bv0pf/AACLJeOIIgcjwfjYgnItmau-a?dl=0

```
x = importdata('data.txt') %data in timedomain [voltage]
t = importdata('time.txt') %time [s]
fs = sampling frequency

w_c = 2*pi*1700; %cut off freq. 1700 Hz
n = 1; %1st order filter
[zb,pb,kb] = butter(n,2*pi*w_c,'low','s'); % analog butterworth filter with zeros og poles output
[bb,ab] = zp2tf(zb,pb,kb); % z&p to a transferfunc.
[hb,wb] = freqs(bb,ab,1e3); %making shure that the damping is correct
[b,a] = bilinear(bb,ab,fs); % analog to digital filter
x_filter = filter(b,a,x); % apply filter on the data
```

I'm unsure about the approach of filtering time-domain data is correct? The data is modeled using a logarithmic scaling of the time in order to gain both early and late changes in the voltage decay. how do i determine a sample frequency for that?

Comment: can you give some sample data?Read [mcve]

Comment: edited with data and data import

Comment: You could resample your non-uniformly sampled data to obtain a uniformly sampled time and data vector, but I don't know if that will help you, because the logarithmic data would result in a relatively long linear uniformly sampled data. Take a look at the `resample` function. Also, why not simply use `[b,a] = butter(n,2*pi*w_c,'low'); x_filter = filte(b,a,x);`?

Comment: And of course, `filte` should be `filter` in my comment.